# For some reason the alert dialog will not open, but no errors are being given

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

So me and a friend have gotten pretty far with our code. But when I press the icon in the ActionBar, the dialog does not open. Any help would be grateful. Below are specific parts of the code that should allow the alert dialog to occur.

```
protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogListener =
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case 0: // Take picture
                        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri (MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                        if (mMediaUri == null) {
                            // display an error
                            Toast.makeText (UploadActivity.this, R.string.error_external_storage,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                        } else {
                            takePhotoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
                            startActivityForResult (takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1: // Take video
                        Intent videoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri (MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
                        if (mMediaUri == null) {
                            // display an error
                            Toast.makeText (UploadActivity.this, R.string.error_external_storage,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                        } else {
                            videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
                            videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
                            videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 6); // 0 = lowest res
                            startActivityForResult (videoIntent, TAKE_VIDEO_REQUEST);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2: // Choose picture
                        Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        choosePhotoIntent.setType ("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult (choosePhotoIntent, PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                        break;
                    case 3: // Choose video
                        Intent chooseVideoIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        chooseVideoIntent.setType ("video/*");
                        Toast.makeText (UploadActivity.this, R.string.video_file_size_warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                        startActivityForResult (chooseVideoIntent, PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
                        break;

                }
            }

            private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaType) {
                // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
                // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
                if (isExternalStorageAvailable ()) {
                    // get the URI

                    // 1. Get the external storage directory
                    String appName = UploadActivity.this.getString (R.string.app_name);
                    File mediaStorageDir = new File (
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                            appName);

                    // 2. Create our subdirectory
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists ()) {
                        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs ()) {
                            Log.e (TAG, "Failed to create directory.");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    // 3. Create a file name
                    // 4. Create the file
                    File mediaFile;
                    Date now = new Date ();
                    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format (now);

                    String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath () + File.separator;
                    if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
                        mediaFile = new File (path + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
                    } else if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                        mediaFile = new File (path + "VID_" + timestamp + ".mp4");
                    } else if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                        mediaFile = new File (path + "Audio_" + timestamp + ".mp3");
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }

                    Log.d (TAG, "File: " + Uri.fromFile (mediaFile));

                    // 5. Return the file's URI
                    return Uri.fromFile (mediaFile);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState ();

                if (state.equals (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

And this is the onCreate part of the code:

```
Map<String, String> networkDetails = getConnectionDetails ();
    if (networkDetails.isEmpty ()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (UploadActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage (R.string.no_internet_connection)
        .setTitle (R.string.login_error_title)
        .setPositiveButton (android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish ();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
        dialog.show ();
```

And then for the ActionBar:

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId ();

    switch(itemId) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            ParseUser.logOut ();
            navigateToLogin ();
            break;
        case R.id.action_post:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (UploadActivity.this);
            builder.setItems (R.array.camera_choices, mDialogListener);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
            dialog.show ();
            break;


     }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

}
```

I'm really puzzled as to why it won't open when I click on the icon in the actionable. I'm sure I'm missing something I just can't figure it out.

Oncreateoptionsmenu:

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.upload_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".UploadActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
      app:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/logout"
      android:orderInCategory="300" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_upload"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_upload"
      android:title="@string/action_upload"
      android:orderInCategory="220"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You're showing a lot of the code that runs once the dialog is open, but it sounds like the problem is how the menu / action bar is configured. Please post your onCreateOptionsMenu, and maybe your menu resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving two totally different IDs.

In your menu.xml,

```
android:id="@+id/action_upload"
```

And onCreateOptionsMenu your are giving different id,

```
 case R.id.action_post:
```

this should be the one.

And again upload_menu in onCreateOptionsMenu you are inflating is what you have given name here is menu.xml.